# Azure data factory : Process previous date data

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have been trying to find a way to dynamically set the `start` and `end` properties of the pipeline. The reason for this is to process a time series of files 5 days before the current day of the pipeline execution.

I try to set this in the pipeline JSON:

```
"start": "Date.AddDays(SliceStart, -5)"
"start": "Date.AddDays(SliceEnd, -5)"
```

and when publishing through VS2015, I get the error below:

```
Unable to convert 'Date.AddDays(SliceEnd, -5)' to a DateTime value. 
Please use ISO8601 DateTime format such as \"2014-10-01T13:00:00Z\" 
for UTC time, or \"2014-10-01T05:00:00-8:00\" for Pacific Standard 
Time. If the timezone designator is omitted, the system will consider 
it denotes UTC time by default. Hence, \"2014-10-01\" will be 
converted to \"2014-10-01T00:00:00Z\" automatically..
","code":"InputIsMalformedDetailed"
```

What could be the other ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to set this at the pipeline level dynamically, which won't work. You need to deal with it when you provision the time slices against the dataset and in the activity.

Use the JSON attribute called **Offset** within the **availability** block for the dataset and within the **scheduler** block for the activity.

This will use the time slice start value configured by the interval and frequency and offset it by the given value in day/hours/minutes etc.

For example (in the dataset):

```
// etc....
},
"availability": {
  "frequency": "Day",
  "interval": 1,
  "style": "StartOfInterval",
  "offset": "-5.00:00:00" //minus 5 days
}
//etc....
```

You'll need to configure this in both places, otherwise the activity will fail validation at deployment time.

Check out this Microsoft article for details on all the attributes you can use to configure more complex time slice scenarios.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-create-pipelines

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Is it possible to use offset for changing the time zone of data factory?